# Are multiple dynamoDB queries in a single API request bad practice

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling, serverless

I'm trying to create my first DynamoDB based project and I'm having some trouble figuring out the best practices working with a NoSQL database.

My usecase currently is storing users and teams. I have a table that has a partition key of either `USER#{userId}` or `TEAM{#teamId}`. If the PK is `TEAM{#teamId}` I store records with SK either `TEAM#{teamId}` for team details, or `USER#{userId}` for the user's details in the team (`acceptedInvite`, `joinDate` etc). I also have a GSI based on the `userId/email` column that allows me to query all the teams a user has been invted to, or the user's team, depending on the value of `acceptedInvite` field. Attached screenshots of the table structure at the moment:

[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4GsO.png)

[The GSI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY0To.png)

In my application I have an access pattern of getting a team's team members, given a user id.

Currently, I'm doing two queries in my lambda function:

- Get user's team, by querying the GSI on `PK = {userId} and fitler acceptedInvite = true`
- Get the team data by querying the table on `PK = {teamId} and SK begins_with USER#`

This works fine, but I'm concerned I need to preform two separate DynamoDB calls in my API function.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to represent this access pattern and if multiple dynamoDB calls are actually that bad, since I cannot see another way to do this.

Any kind of feedback is appreciated!

Comment: How many users and teams will you have in total?

Comment: I'd like to be able to have at least around 10-15k users spread in 6-8k teams

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid making two queries like this is to supply the API caller with all the information needed to make a single DynamoDB request. For your case this means supplying the caller with the teamId. You can do this as either as part of a list operation response, or if it is the authenticated user, then as part of their claims in a JWT.